# Correct model for street name and multiple street numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model

I'm a newbie using Rails, I would like to know how to correctly set this type of Model:

Table Places

- Street Name
- Street Number
- Street Number
- Street Number
- ... Unlimited Street Number

I have to save several street numbers for every street name.

What's the best way?

---

Updated:

@RoDoTiQ @Pavan thank you for your answers! What do you think about this?

```rb
class Street < ActiveRecord::Base
  # I try to mantain the "Standard Street" with one Street Number
end

class Custom_Street <  Street
  # Custom Street with principal Street Number and additional Street Numbers
  has_many :additional_street_numbers
end

class Additional_Street_Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :custom_street
end
```

Comment: Looks Good.You have to accept one of the answers if you found it helpful :)

Comment: Certainly, it's a pity I can't accept both answers :) Thank you very much for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more relevant way would be a `has_many through`

```
Class Place < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :street_numbers
has_many :streets,through: :street_numbers

end

Class Street < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :street_numbers
has_many :places,through: :street_numbers

end

Class StreetNumber < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :place
belongs_to :street

end
```

For more details,see these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)**

Answer (score 0):

You should do Active record association through the has_many operator

something like that:

```
class Street < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :street_numbers
end

class Street_Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :street
end
```

Please check this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more details.